# Running Python code in Aptana Studio 3 - executes in Firefox

Tags: python, python-2.7, aptana, aptana3

I'm new to Python and Aptana. I'm doing some tutorials on Python using Aptana and the first time I ran some sample code it was all fine.
Now I've installed GitHub and ipython and now when I want to execute python code from Aptana it keeps on using Firefox Internal Server to run it, which is not what I want. I just want it to run in the Console.
Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

[image]